# TortoiseGit - git not found

Tags: git, msysgit, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit with msysGit installed with the `msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729.exe` and it works in a very strange way:

- on the `About` windows it says it can't find git, even if all the operations seems to complete ok
- on the `Settings` window, `General` tab, `MSysGit` section, the version is blank even with the correct path set (....\msysGit\bin)
- on the `Settings` window, `Git\Config` tab, any attempt to alter and save the settings lead to some stange text-less error, and the only way to close the window is by `Cancel' button
- on every operation it seems to look for git.exe on all the folders in path, which is at least strange, given that it knows exactly where to find the executable

The first three points are not present if I install msysGit with the `Git-1.6.4-preview20090730.exe`, even if the path is set the same in both cases (....\msysGit\cmd)

What can I do to make TortoiseGit recognise git installation from the `msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729.exe`?

---

Environment:

- Git-1.6.4-preview20090730.exe
- msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729.exe
- TortoiseGit 1.0.2.0 32bit

---

**EDIT:**

I don't want to put `msysGit\bin` in path, just `msysGit\cmd`.

If I simply replace the files from `msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729.exe` with the files from an `Git-1.6.4-preview20090730.exe` installation, then TortoiseGit seems to recognize the git version and allows me to edit the Git\Config section in the settings. This is at least strange, given that the rest of the environment is not modified at all.

As soon as I restore the `msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729.exe` files, TortoiseGit cease to function properly.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realize the fullinstall version had different binaries. I just use the regular version.

Comment: do you really need msysGit-fullinstall? if you do file an issue with TortoiseGit

Comment: @Mauricio: msysGit-fullinstall allows me to use Git 1.6.4.2

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. Please file an issue with TortoiseGit...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While this question is still hot... some nice people contributed lots of bugfixes to all three projects, so this is what I did to get TortoiseGit on Win7x64, previously failing on all combinations:

1. install **mSysGit** (network installer) into C:\msysgit, it will download the source and compile it leaving you in a bash git prompt.
   Stable version: **msysGit-netinstall-1.7.2.3-preview20100911.exe** 13 sep
2. install **Git “preview”** into C:\Program Files (x86)\Git, choose OpenSSH for ssh link
   Stable version: **Git-1.7.2.3-preview20100911.exe** 13 sep
3. install **tortoisegit** into C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit, (x64 version) and configure it’s settings specifying the git path (C:\msysgit\bin) and menu integration.
   Stable version: **TortoiseGit-1.5.6.0-64bit.msi** 25 sep

This setup picked up my existing git repos made on WinXP x86 with older versions of the packages, and seems fairly stable and fully functional.

Answer (score 9):

I've had nothing but problems with TortoiseGit.

However, discovering the following enabled me to give up sooner:

In your Path (in Control Panel->System->Advanced Settings->Environment Settings), add a path that contains git.exe (msysgit\bin or msysgit\git?  TortoiseGit's instructions sure the hell don't tell me, so how should I know).  Then open a command prompt and try running git.exe.  It'll probably complain that it can't find libcurl-4.dll.  So, you'll find that this dll file exists in msysgit\mingw\bin.  Add this directory to your Path (or copy the dll if you prefer).

Now, the setup in TortoiseGit will finally appear to work.  Clicking the "Check Now" button will actually tell you the version of git you're using instead of mysteriously going blank or popping up a useless error window.

When you try using TortoiseGit now, you'll get a blank progress bar that does nothing and you can't close it.  Congratulations!  Now you can give up and delete this garbage until someone cares enough to prepare it for human consumption.  (can you tell I'm fed up with this software?)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with TortoiseGit-1.0.2.0-64bit and msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729 on Vista 64-bit SP1, except TortoiseGIT actually worked when it was all done!

Answer (score 2):

This might be obvious, but it's not clear from your post. Do you have `msysgit\bin` in your system path?

Also, this isn't quite answering your question, but I've found that TortoiseGit lacks polish. I prefer using [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/).

Comment: IMO it's the other way around, GitExtensions lacks polish compared to TortoiseGit

Answer (score 2):

Well, since my post, I actually got TortoiseGit working on one of my two systems.  Adding the msysgit\mingw\bin directory to the path (so that git.exe could find libcurl-4.dll and thus not cause everything to silently fail) was the final key.  I was able to do it using the default TortoisePlink.exe and didn't have to set GIT_SSH or anything like that.  I could say it was easy (in retrospect, it's easy enough..) but in truth it took about two coding sessions that I would have preferred to spend more productively.

Comment: I also just added msysgit\mingw\bin to system path and it worked: http://blog.casualdev.net/2009/10/tortoisegit-cannot-find-libcurl-4dll.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that bash prompt from `msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729.exe` also adds `msysGit\mingw\bin` to path, so in order to use **TortoiseGit** and/or **Git Extensions** I have copied all the files from `msysGit\mingw\bin` to `msysGit\bin` and set the location to `git.exe` in both tools.

Answer (score 1):

### **Answer for recent versions of TortoiseGit (>= 1.8.16 and >= 2.0)**

As mentioned on the [FAQ](https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/) TortoiseGit requires a command line git.exe. There are several [alternatives available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32427897/3906760), however, [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io) is recommended which should work out of the box.

The recommended order is to install TortoiseGit first. TortoiseGit will then (hopefully automatically) detect the installed git.exe by checking for Git for Windows installations, looking on the `%PATH%` or manual configuration ([TortoiseGit settings](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html)).