# TortoiseGit do I have to download MsysGit or Git first?

Tags: tortoisegit

I'm finding the manual a bit confusing on this issue, and searching previous answers confused me more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Git (as in [Full Installer for Git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=%22Full%20installer%20for%20official%20Git%20for%20Windows%22)) is enough, from the [pre-requisite page](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/SetupHowTo).
It only needs "Git for Windows".

[image]

**See "[Difference between msysgit and Cygwin + git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/difference-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417)" for more between MSysGit and "Git for Windows".**
The trick, though, is that the "Git for Windows" packaged is often referenced by users as "msysgit", even though msysgit is actually the full development environment.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the [FAQ](https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/) TortoiseGit requires a command line git.exe. There are several [alternatives available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32427897/3906760), however, [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io) is recommended which should work out of the box.

The recommended order is to install TortoiseGit first. TortoiseGit will then (hopefully automatically) detect the installed git.exe by checking for Git for Windows installations, looking on the `%PATH%` or manual configuration ([TortoiseGit settings](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html)).

Comment: This line keeps on confusing me:
"The recommended order is to install TortoiseGit first."
If I install this **FIRST**, then how can it find Git for Windows which I haven't installed yet? So shouldn't it be "A git.exe (like Git for Windows) first, then TortoiseGit?

Comment: TortoiseGit does not require a git.exe during installation. However, Git for Windows tries to detect whether TortoiseGit is already installed.