# Upgrade Git for Windows when using TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, beyondcompare4

I am using TortoiseGit v2.8, and my Git version is `2.18.0.windows.1` (according to `git --version`). I want to upgrade my Git version to the latest version (v2.1), but I am not sure if TortoiseGit will work with v2.21 of Git for Windows.

I want to upgrade Git for Windows as the Diff tool I want to use, Beyond Compare 4 seems to indicate Git for Windows v2.2.

Will upgrading my Git for Windows version interfere with TortoiseGit functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does TortoiseGit work with PortableGit-x.x.x.x-previewyyyyyy? What are compatible git versions for TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047483/does-tortoisegit-work-with-portablegit-x-x-x-x-previewyyyyyy-what-are-compatibl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the [latest Git version is 2.21](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Second, you can simply unarchive [`PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.21.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit.7z.exe) and change the Git path within [TortoiseGit settings](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html), to test it out.

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/SettingsMain.png]

I suspect it will work just fine with Git 2.21.
And you would still have your old Git installation to fall back to if the portable one had any issue.

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseGit works perfectkly fine with [Git for Windows 2.21](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).